# Minimalmodbus I can read data, but i cannot write it (RTU)

Tags: python, pyserial, modbus, pymodbus, minimalmodbus

I´m using minimalmodbus python library to communicate my Raspberry Pi with "Spacelogic Thermostat TC900" (RTU).

I have no problem reading the data, but when I try to write on it, the console shows the next error:

```
No communication with the instrument (no answer)
```

From my point of view, this error has no sense, because if I can read, I must have communication with the instrument.

minimalmodbus homepage: https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

minimalmodbus write_bits page: https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apiminimalmodbus.html?highlight=write_bits#minimalmodbus.Instrument.write_bits

My code:

```
#imports
import minimalmodbus
import serial

#instr creation
instr = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1)

#instr config
instr.serial.baudrate = 9600
instr.serial.timeout = 1
instr.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU
instr.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_ODD
instr.serial.bytesize = 8
instr.serial.stopbits = 1
instr.debug = True

try:
    print("READ:")
    print(instr.read_bits(4, 3, functioncode=1))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error reading coil: " , e)

try:
    print("WRITE")
    instr.write_bits(5, [True,False])
except Exception as e:
    print("Error writing Coil: " , e)
```

Console output:

```
READ:
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 6 bytes back): '\x01\x01\x00\x04\x00\x03=Ê' (01 01 00 04 00 03 3D CA)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 25577762.09 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x01\x01\x01\x04PK' (01 01 01 04 50 4B) (6 bytes), roundtrip time: 42.5 ms. Timeout for reading: 1000.0 ms.

[0, 0, 1]
WRITE
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 8 bytes back): '\x01\x0f\x00\x05\x00\x02\x01\x01ÓW' (01 0F 00 05 00 02 01 01 D3 57)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port /dev/ttyUSB0
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 1.98 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 4.01 ms, time since read: 2.03 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '' () (0 bytes), roundtrip time: 1001.8 ms. Timeout for reading: 1000.0 ms.

Error writing Coil:  No communication with the instrument (no answer)
```

I tried **pymodbus** too, but the same happened, I only could read data.

I thought the error could be on the thermostat, but I used **Modbus Poll** to write on it and I had no problem.

Comment: Can you please confirm that Modbus Poll is sending exactly the same request (it should show you the bytes its sending; check if those match the write request in your log). A [manual I found](https://community.exchange.se.com/krefy84679/attachments/krefy84679/system-architects/98/2/TC900%20Series%20Digital%20Fan%20Coil%20Thermostat%20Installation%20Sheet.pdf) does not mention any coils.

Comment: Brits is right. If you want to change the fan speed (is that it?) you have to write an integer to register 5, you cannot write to any of those coils. Maybe you thought the writing operation was successful with Modpoll because you did not get any errors?